# Autoclick on a button in popped up dialog box

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How to auto-click on Yes or No button on a dialog box which pops up on a website?

One crude way I'm using is to set a timer to trigger click on button if the dialog box is visible once every 100ms.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following options:

- For native `confirm()` or `alert()`  methods, then you cannot click programatically on the buttons to dismiss. They can be closed only on user interaction.
- For html based dialog box (bootstrap modal for example), then initiate a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) listener with a [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) of 50ms (debouncing will allow you to reduce the evaluation calls on bunch of elements added). When the modal elements are inserted into DOM, trigger a `click` event on the necessary button from the mutation observer handler.

Comment: Can you explain better the "debounce" part?

Comment: @Xan Thanks for the tip. Updated.